# Is there a way to move objects in the viewport and have them collide with other objects in the scene?

Tags: physics, transforms, snapping, 3d-manipulator

I'm trying to dress a bookshelf setpiece with a bunch of models of books, and it's really tedious to try to get things like slanted books to rest right; to get a book to rest on the edge of another book involves tons of tweaking rotations and translates to keep it from intersecting while still looking like they're touching. I'm trying to do a bunch of things like this:

[image: model of a slanted book between two other books on a bookshelf]

Houdini recently added a feature called "physically based layout", in which you can manipulate objects in the scene using translate handles and the object will collide with the scene as you move it around ([they have a little gif of it here](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/solaris/tutorial_3.html#physically-based-layout)) -- does Blender have something like that? I've been using snapping, and it works okay but often fails to detect the geometry I want it to snap to the face it's hitting. And barring that, is there a way I can use Blender's physics system to help me settle these slanted books into place? Thank you!

Comment: yes it would be a nice idea, it would allow to put objects on the ground too, but I don't think it already exists though